# Quarantine protocol when reaching small airports in Germany from main airports

Tags: covid-19, connecting-flights, quarantine

I have to travel soon to Leipzig (Germany) from Dublin (Ireland), and most flights (from Lufthansa, KLM, Ryanair) either go to other bigger airports (such as Frankfurt, Berlin, or Dresden) or go to these and couple them with a train to Leipzig.

As of May 21st, Dublin is still a risk area for most German states, so I would have to quarantine when I arrive there. However, I am having trouble finding any information on whether they allow for taking an ICE to another airport, which (it seems to me) would completely defeat the purpose of a quarantine upon arrival.

Does someone know where to find information about this, or what the current protocol is? Would I have to find a direct flight to Leipzig?

Comment: (I have been told that the requirement is to quarantine in your *final destination*, so maybe taking a train is not a problem.)

Comment: I would be highly surprised, if there were flights from Dresden to Leipzig, since this is like an hour of travel by car. Since FFP2 masks are mandatory on many trains, and the rules state, that you have to quarantine at your final destination, you can book one and travel to Leipzig - just keep the mask on. If you feel better about it, you could rent a car, but prices are going through the roof currently. I don't know, whether you still have to annouce your arrival via an online form, or not. If in question, contact local health authorities in Leipzig (Gesundheitsamt).

Comment: It is difficult to keep track of all the changes in the corona regulations, but certain parts of Ireland are only considered a 'risk area' and not a 'high risk area'. With the latest changes to the quarantine regulations, are you not excempt from quarantine if you come from a 'risk area' and present a negative corona test? At least that is my understanding of the current rules.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The list [here](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html) puts Dublin in the "risk area" but not "high risk". Do you have a link to the rules saying that "risk areas" do not require quarantine?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I am looking around [this link](https://www.berlin.de/corona/massnahmen/einreisen/#ausnahmen) for protocol.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff see [the third bullet point under 'Absonderungspflicht'](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/service/gesetze-und-verordnungen/guv-19-lp/coronaeinreisev.html). For people arriving from a Risikogebiet, the quarantine requirement is lifted immediately when you submit a negative test. This can even be done before arrival (see "[Wer kann sich freitesten?](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/faq-tests-einreisende.html)")

Comment: @ChrisH Thank you! If you post that as an answer I could accept it.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff ok, I'll do that :)

Comment: @ChrisH In the page you sent, it does say "If you have stayed in a risk area, you have to go home immediately after arrival - or to some other accommodation at the destination - and isolate yourself for ten days (quarantine at home) ." Are you suggesting the regulation has since changed?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I'll include that in the answer

Comment: @PedroTamaroff the answer's there now, but to address that specifically: the regulation hasn't changed, you're just able to free yourself from it by submitting a negative test certificate (as long as you're coming from a simple risk area, which Dublin currently is).

Comment: @ChrisH Your answer is correct, but the regulation *did* change on May 12th and there may still be advice found online based on the old rules. Before May 12th, when coming from a risk area, you could not 'test yourself free' until having spent at least 5 days in quarantine in Germany. The option to provide a negative test before entry and hence avoid quarantine altogether was introduced on May 12th with the new federal regulation.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Pedro was asking about a change specifically in relation to the page I linked, which is up-to-date with the May 12th regulations.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised you call Leipzig a small airport compared to Dresden. According to Wikipedia, Dresden had 1.6 mio passengers in 2019 while Leipzig had 2.6 mio. There is THE Leipzig airport: *Leipzig/Halle/Schkeuditz* and there's *Leipzig-Altenburg* that's much smaller but a typical Ryanair target. Don't confuse these two! Take care!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you found in the comments, Dublin [is currently a Risikogebiet ("risk area")](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html).

In principle this means you have to quarantine on arrival, but the regulations for arrivals from simple risk areas are quite relaxed. Provided you haven't been in a high incidence area or a virus variant area, a negative test is enough to immediately free you from the quarantine requirement. See [the third bullet point under 'Absonderungspflicht'](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/service/gesetze-und-verordnungen/guv-19-lp/coronaeinreisev.html):

> Die häusliche Quarantäne kann vorzeitig beendet werden, wenn ein Genesenennachweis, ein Impfnachweis oder ein negativer Testnachweis über das Einreiseportal der Bundesrepublik unter https://www.einreiseanmeldung.de übermittelt wird. Nach Voraufenthalt in Hochinzidenzgebieten kann eine Testung frühestens fünf Tage nach Einreise vorgenommen werden. Nach Aufenthalt in Virusvariantengebieten dauert die Quarantäne 14 Tage und eine vorzeitige Beendigung der Quarantäne ist nicht möglich.

> The home quarantine can be ended early if a certificate of recovery, vaccination passport, or negative test certificate is submitted via the Arrival Portal of the Federal Republic of Germany at https://www.einreiseanmeldung.de. After stays in a high incidence area the test can only be taken five days after arrival. After stays in a virus variant area the quarantine lasts for 14 days and cannot be shortened.

The negative test [can even be submitted before arrival, in which case you won't have to worry about the quarantine at all](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/coronavirus-infos-reisende/faq-tests-einreisende.html#c20222):

> **Wer kann sich freitesten?**
> Nach Voraufenthalt in einem einfachen Risikogebiet kann die häusliche Quarantäne vorzeitig beendet werden, wenn ein negativer Testnachweis über das Einreiseportal der Bundesrepublik unter https://einreiseanmeldung.de übermittelt wird. Die Quarantäne kann dann ab dem Zeitpunkt der Übermittlung beendet werden. Wird der Nachweis bereits vor Einreise übermittelt, so ist keine Quarantäne erforderlich.
> Nach Voraufenthalt in Hochinzidenzgebieten kann eine Testung frühestens fünf Tage nach Einreise vorgenommen werden. Nach Aufenthalt in Virusvariantengebieten dauert die Quarantäne 14 Tage und eine vorzeitige Beendigung der Quarantäne ist nicht möglich.

> **Who can test out of quarantine**
> After stays in a simple risk area the home quarantine can be ended early if a negative test certificate is submitted to the arrival portal at https://einreiseanmeldung.de. The quarantine can then be ended from the time of submission. If the certificate is already submitted before arrival, no quarantine is required.
> After stays in a high incidence area the test can be performed no earlier than five days after arrival. After stays in a virus variant area the quarantine is 14 days long and there is no possibility to end the quarantine early.

(Both English translations are my own. For some context: I'm not a native German speaker but I've lived here since 2010 and it's been my everyday language at work for over 5 years now)